# Empty input text field in $_POST (Codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter

I have this code in my template

```
          <?php echo form_open('cart/add'); ?>
          <?php echo form_hidden('id', $product['id']); ?>
          <?php echo form_hidden('title', $product['title']); ?>
          <?php echo form_hidden('price', $product['price']); ?>
          <?php echo form_input('quantity'); ?>
          <?php echo form_submit('cart_submit', 'Add to cart'); ?>
```

When I submit this form to controller `quantity` variable always empty, no matter what I enter in input field. But there is proper value in headers. Other variables also passed with proper value. May be this is some codeigniter specific configuration?

Comment: it works i just tried it -- are you sure you loaded the form helper? http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html Otherwise post more of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do 1 thing that at the end close the form like form_close();
Or may be you did not load form helper. So either use $this->load->helper('form'); in your controller or just load the form helper in config/autoload.php file like $autoload['helper'] = array('form');